# resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers.!

Tags: jquery

I have bought YOAST and SMUSH it ,a lot of things has been much better.

now I have 1 problem which has to be solved .

when I run GTMETRIX I get this error:

> resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources:

```
computertechnet.nl/wp-content/plugins/cherry-lazy-load/css/lazy-load.css?ver=1.0
computertechnet.nl/wp-content/plugins/cherry-lazy-load/js/cherry.lazy-load.js?ver=1.0
computertechnet.nl/wp-content/plugins/cherry-lazy-load/js/device.min.js?ver=1.0.0
```

how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
/** 
* Remove Query strings from Static Resources. 
*/
function remove_cssjs_ver( $src ) {
    if( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) )
    $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_ver', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_ver', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use online url encoders like

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

so your urls might look like

`computertechnet.nl%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcherry-lazy-load%2Fcss%2Flazy-load.css%3Fver%3D1.0%20`